# Customize Bezier Curve in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can i achive this both curve in my flutter application I try to do but I endup with so weird  results...

This is imge with I want to achive

[image]

And this is my stating code-

```
ClipPath(
    clipper: BackgroudCliper(),
    child: Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.20),
    ),
  ),

Path getClip(Size size) {
var path = Path();
path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 20, size.height / 20, 0, size.height);
path.close();
return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello here is my way to do the waves.

```
const double desiredWaveHeigth = 100;
var path = Path();
//This line move the path at the left bottom corner
path.moveTo(0,size.height);
// This creates a line form left bottom corner to the desired height (start of the first wave)
path.lineTo(0.0, desiredWaveHeigth);

//Create the first wave(wave up). From start point(previous point) to the second wave start. 
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 6, 60, size.width / 3, desiredWaveHeigth);
//Create the second wave (wave down). From end of the first wave to start of the third wave. 
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, 140, 2 * size.width / 3, desiredWaveHeigth);
//Create the third wave (wave up). From end of the second wave to the rigth edge of the screen(width) and desired height(100)
path.quadraticBezierTo(5 * size.width / 6, 60, size.width, desiredWaveHeigth);

//Create a line from end of the third wave to the right bottom corner.
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
//Create a line from right bottom corner to the initial position. Note that the last point must be the same of the initial point
path.lineTo(0,size.height);
path.close();
```

Comment: It really help full thank you but I want that curve bottom to top and your curve goes top to bottom how can I change it?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can check it again.